# Linux script which checks users and their groups

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am completely new to the shell scripting. Please help me out in below requirement. Thanks

Let us think a,b,c,d are the part of group z.
I want to write a script which runs every day particular time (example 8:00 AM)
The script should look if the user is a part of group z, if he is a part of group z then run particular command (example whoami)

Please help out

Comment: How are you checking which user belongs to the group. What have you tried till now. Please show some code and elaborate your requirement.

Comment: I am using groups user_name
and 
getent group group_name | grep -o user_name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
G='cdrom';
if [ `groups | grep cdrom | wc -l` -eq 1 ];
then whoami;
else echo "Not in group $G";
fi
```

This should print the user's username with "whoami" if the user is in the group "cdrom".  If they're not in the group "cdrom" then it should print "Not in group cdrom".  Then you can set it up as a cronjob by editing your crontab like `0 8 * * * /path/to/script` with the command `crontab -e` which will make the program run at 8 am every day.

Please note that this has very basic functionality just so that you can get the idea.  You'll have the edit the script to really do anything useful.

Comment: I believe you can reduce this slightly with `groups | grep -c "$G"`  ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: Counting the number of matches is an antipattern; see [useless use of `wc -l`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)